# React Axios get a 404 with jsonbin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm using JSONBin to mock-up data from a JSON fake list of users.
The code works fine in a public bin but I'm getting a 404 req as soon I send headers in Axios

My code is:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`${baseURL}/63be860ddfc...[bin-ID etc]/latest`, {
      headers: {
        "X-Master-Key": "<MASTER-KEY-HERE>",
        "X-Access-Key": "<ACCESS-KEY-HERE>"
      }
    })
    .then((res) => {
      setUsers(res.data.record);
      console.log('theRes:', res)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('theError:', error);
      setError(error);
    })
  }, []);
```

Console error is:

```
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
config: 
adapter:(2) ['xhr', 'http']
data: undefined
env: {FormData: ƒ, Blob: ƒ}
headers: 
AxiosHeaders Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"
Content-Type: null
X-Access-Key:"<THE-ACCESS-KEY-...>"
X-Master-Key:"<THE-MASTER-KEY-...>"
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): (...)
[[Prototype]]: Object
maxBodyLength: -1
maxContentLength: -1
method:"get"
timeout: 0
transformRequest: [ƒ]
transformResponse: [ƒ]
```

I followed this documentation https://jsonbin.io/api-reference/bins/read but I guess I missed something

Comment: FYI: You are not supposed to use `X-Access-Key` and `X-Master-Key` at the same time, you need only one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a configuration issue on the .env file.
The var url was adding an extra "/"

```
baseURL = <URL>/
```

result was: `<URL>//63be860ddfc`